# generic thread framework vs asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, generics, android-asynctask

I have a few questions about the the usages of a generic thread framework(for a specific amount of jobs of course) vs the usage of many asyntasks. 
   I would like to know if it is better to have many asyntasks for small jobs, a handler thread when the job takes a bit longer or it is better to have a generic thread by yourself having generic jobs with a notification system built on top of the the running thread(or a subclass, same story).

My idea is for creating thread that handles different jobs without knowing beforehand which are the jobs. This goes in the direction of creating a sort of small framework for handling different generic jobs. 
   For example my approach goes in the direction of the code below:

```
    public (abstract if you want to extend and add something on top) class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = WorkerThread();
    private List<WorkTask> syncQueue = new ArrayList< WorkTask >();
    private boolean clearQueue = false;
    public WorkerThread() {

    }


    public void stop(boolean clear) {
        clearQueue = clear;
        this.stopWorker = true;
    }

    public void addTask(WorkerTask task) {
        synchronized (syncQueue) {
            if (task != null && !getSynQueue().contains(task)) {
                getSynQueue().add(task);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stopWorker) {
            WorkerTask task = null;
            synchronized (syncQueue) {
                if (!getSynQueue().isEmpty()) {
                    task = getSynQueue().get(0);
                }
            }
            if (task != null) {
                try {
                    task.run();
                    synchronized (syncQueue) {
                        if (!getSynQueue().isEmpty()) {
                            getSynQueue().remove(task);
                            //notify something/someone
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in running the task." + e.getMessage());
                    synchronized (syncQueue) {
                       //again u can notify someone
                    }
                } finally {
                    //here you can actually notify someone of success
                }
            }
        }
        if(clearQueue){
           getSynQueue().clear();
        }
    }
    private List<WorkerTask> getSynQueue() {
        return this.syncQueue;
    }
}
```

Here the task is the abstract base class that all the jobs extend. 
   Then on top of this thread or a subclass of this class can be an  observer that notifies when something went wrong with the jobs/tasks.
   So far, as I know, the pros and cons for my approach are like that:
   **Thread**:

**Pros:** 
   1. Long time operations. 
   2. Centralized. 
   3. Scalable. 
   4. Once you have it properly tested it will work smoothly.

**Cons** 
   1. Complex architecture. 
   2. Hard to maintain. 
   3. Over-engineering for small jobs.

**AsynTask:**

**Pros** 
   1. Easy to be used. 
   2. Good for short-time operation jobs. 
   3. Easy to maintain/understand.

**Cons** 
   1. Cannot scale that much, you need to stick to doInBackground and onPostExecute. 
   2. Not good for long-time operation jobs.

If I missed something please correct me. 
Final question would be, when the architecture gets a bit big with a lot of requests, short-time, long-time, isn't it better to try and make a generic framework that can handle it both rather than do it with asynctasks there, maybe handlerthread in other parts, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask should be used for short operations. From the official documentation:

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

Therefore, if the operation is designed to take longer than a few seconds, it is recommended to use the concurrent package. E.g of operations are, storing a file, a picture, a login, etc. 
However, Asynctask has also a few limitations as it can be seen in the link below:
[AsyncTask limitations](http://blogs.innovationm.com/multiple-asynctask-in-android/)

> There is a limit of how many tasks can be run simultaneously. Since AsyncTask uses a thread pool executor with max number of worker threads (128) and the delayed tasks queue has fixed size 10. If you try to execute more than 138 AsyncTasks the app will crash with java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException.

Also, between Api 1.6 and 3.0 there is no way to customize the AsyncTask. It can run tasks in parallel but no customization possible. A
Between API 3.0 and API 4.3.1 there is a default fixed delayed queue size of 10, a minimum number of tasks, 5, and a maximum number of tasks 128. However, after API 3.0, one can define its own executor. 
Therefore, if you have a number of minimum 16 tasks to run, the first 5 will start, the next 10 will go into the queue, but from the 16th a new worker thread will be allocated. After version 4.4(kitkat), the number of parallel asynctasks depends on the amount of processors that a device has:

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT =    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);
```

The aforementioned details, make the AsyncTask usable only in very specific cases, like loading an image or a file from or to the storage.

On the hand a generic threading framework(or library) can be easily extendable and customizable. Example of libraries is the RxJava that is easily customizable. Using RxJava one can specify task to run on either UI thread and background. Also, for loading/saving pictures asynchronously to/on the sdcard, one can use different libraries like Picasso or Glide.